# How can I make Vista behave like XP when Tab is pressed after WinKey?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

When I used to press first <kbd>WinKey</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> (one after the other) in XP, focus would shift from the Start button to the quick launch bar. From there, I could use the arrow keys to choose a shortcut, or press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the taskbar.

This doesn't happen in Vista using the "Classic" Start menu. (Other Start menu options are disabled by active directory.) How can I get the XP behavior back?

---

**Update**
I rolled this post back because it was updated to say "<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>," not "<kbd>WinKey</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>," which is a different problem.

Comment: Win+Tab in Vista/7 is for Flip 3D. I know Win+B for the notification area bar and Win+T for the Taskbar icons in Win7 but I'm not sure how you hit quick launch in Vista. :(

Comment: ...actually, maybe Win+(number) will work for the first 10 like the taskbar in Windows 7? Worth a shot.

Comment: indeed, Win+Number gives you quick access to the first ten icons, Win+T gives the taskbar focus. There's no quick launch bar anywhere, so Win+Tab was a free shortcut.

Comment: @Phoshi - Vista DOES have a quick launch bar though, right?  But Win+Tab does Flip 3D even in Vista, so...hmm.

Comment: `Win` > `Tab` (windows key followed by the tab key) edits to the question removed this! I have no way of getting focus to the quick launch in Vista unlike in XP where `win` followed by `tab` focused the quick launch. Thanks

Comment: @Shinrai; Agh, brainfart! Completely glossed over vista and straight into win7 there! Sorry @Alan :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a chance to test in Vista and Win, Win again (to lower the start menu but keep it focused), then Tab seems to work for me.

Comment: It turns out can tab to the quick launch, but not with any program that accepts a tab key. If I press `Win + M`, `Win`, `Win`, `tab`, `tab` then the quick launch gets focus. If anyone has a way to restore `Win`, `Tab` then I would love to hear it

Comment: @Alan Doh! You're right.  That's a nuisance, yes.  Glad to see Ctrl+Esc works though (extra keystroke but meh).

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of pressing the active program stealing kbd focus when you press <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd> you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead.

**Solution**

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice. This shows then hides the start menu but keeps it focused. After this a single <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves focus to the quick launch.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>tab</kbd>

This minimises all windows and focuses the desktop, you can then tab around the start menu button, followed by quick launch, task bar and system tray.